# How to make ignored junit steps in cucumber-jvm cause test scenario to fail

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, appium, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber-jvm with appium using eclipse and junit.

Some of my tests stop working halfway through.  They do not overtly fail the junit tests but instead stop working and ignore the remaining steps.

When I look at these steps in junit (through eclipse) they appear to have passed, until I drill into them and see steps have been ignored.

Is there a way to mark any test scenarios with ignored steps as failures rather than as passes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you have a JUnit test case with an `@CucumberOptions` annotation on it.  If you have this, you should be able to make ignored tests fail the build by setting `strict=true`.  e.g.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true)
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```